# Android HTTPS and Cookies, API level 8

Tags: java, android, session, cookies, https

I am writing an Android application which has to connect to a server through HTTPS. The first solution I tried was this one:
(Don't mind the security flaws)

```
final static HostnameVerifier DO_NOT_VERIFY = new HostnameVerifier() {
    public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
        return true;
    }
};
private static void trustAllHosts() {
    // Create a trust manager that does not validate certificate chains
    TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[] { new X509TrustManager() {
        public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
            return new java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] {};
        }

        public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain,
                String authType) throws CertificateException {
        }

        public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain,
                String authType) throws CertificateException {
        }
    } };

    // Install the all-trusting trust manager
    try {
        SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        sc.init(null, trustAllCerts, new java.security.SecureRandom());
             HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("USR_SSL", e.getMessage());
    }
}
//...

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    try {

        URL url = new URL(params[0]);
                    //This is an HTTPS url
        String jsonStr = "";
        if(params.length > 1) {
            jsonStr = params[1];
        }
        HttpsURLConnection urlConn = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        trustAllHosts();
        urlConn.setHostnameVerifier(DO_NOT_VERIFY);
        urlConn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
        urlConn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
        urlConn.setRequestMethod("POST");

        OutputStream os = urlConn.getOutputStream();
        os.write(jsonStr.getBytes());
        os.flush();
//...
```

All fine and dandy (almost), until I realised that I also have to use authentication, session, and all that good stuff. It should have been really fine using:

```
CookieManager cookieManager = new CookieManager();  
CookieHandler.setDefault(cookieManager);
```

but unfortunately we have to support Android API level 8, which means the above two lines of code will not work. Given that, I've scoured the Internet for a few hours trying to build a solution using Apache classes, which seemingly support both HTTPS and Cookies.

This is the code I've managed to sew together:

```
public class ConnectionMediator {
public class MySSLSocketFactory extends SSLSocketFactory {
    SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");

    public MySSLSocketFactory(KeyStore truststore) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyManagementException, KeyStoreException, UnrecoverableKeyException {
        super(truststore);

        TrustManager tm = new X509TrustManager() {
            public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) {
            }

            public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) {
            }

            public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                return null;
            }
        };
        sslContext.init(null, new TrustManager[] { tm }, null);
    }

    @Override
    public Socket createSocket(Socket socket, String host, int port, boolean autoClose) throws IOException, UnknownHostException {
        return sslContext.getSocketFactory().createSocket(socket, host, port, autoClose);
    }

    @Override
    public Socket createSocket() throws IOException {
        return sslContext.getSocketFactory().createSocket();
    }
}
public void tryConnect(String url, String data) {
    try {
        //SSL Stuff
        KeyStore trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
        trustStore.load(null, null);

        SSLSocketFactory sf = new MySSLSocketFactory(trustStore);
        sf.setHostnameVerifier(SSLSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER);

        HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
        HttpProtocolParams.setVersion(params, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
        HttpProtocolParams.setContentCharset(params, HTTP.UTF_8);

        SchemeRegistry registry = new SchemeRegistry();
        registry.register(new Scheme("http", PlainSocketFactory.getSocketFactory(), 80));
        registry.register(new Scheme("https", sf, 443));

        ClientConnectionManager ccm = new ThreadSafeClientConnManager(params, registry);

        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new  DefaultHttpClient(ccm, params);

        //Cookie stuff
        HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
        HttpResponse response = null;
        HttpPost httpPost = null;
        StringEntity tmp = null;

        httpClient.getParams().setParameter(ClientPNames.COOKIE_POLICY, CookiePolicy.RFC_2109);
        httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

        tmp = new StringEntity(data,"UTF-8");
        httpPost.setEntity(tmp);

        response = httpClient.execute(httpPost,localContext);
    } catch(Exception e) {
        Log.d("USR_DEBUG", e.getClass().toString() + ": " + e.getMessage());
    }

}
}
```

At the time of writing this, I get a `NetworkOnMainThreadException`, but this is rather unimportant; what matters and what I wish to point out is that *i have no idea what I'm doing*, as in, to simply connect through by means of HTTPS and also use cookies, one has to use 13 different classes which I've never heard of. Obviously, my knowledge of HTTPS/Java net classes is bordering null, but in spite of this I would have expected something more intuitive. So rather than a "this doesn't work" type of question, my question is "what should I be doing", or even, "how do I learn what I have to do?".

Thank you very much,

a very confused coder

Comment: big part of what you are doing is only because your https certificate is not recognize (most likely a self signed ?)

Comment: Indeed. Until our server decides to do a proper certificate I'm sticking to this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My initial question had two parts to it: first, how to use HTTPS and second, how to also use cookies along with it.

My question wasn't thorough enough, as I had partly answered it already - the code which I had initially posted worked with respect to HTTPS, and the `NetworkOnMainThreadException` occurred because I was not running the code in a separate thread, for example, using `AsyncTask`.

However, to also make proper use of cookies, one should make use of a solution similar to the following:

```
public class State {
    private static HttpContext httpContext;
    public static HttpContext getHttpContext() {
        if(httpContext == null) {
            httpContext = new BasicHttpContext();
            CookieStore cookieStore = getCookieStore();
            httpContext.setAttribute(ClientContext.COOKIE_STORE, cookieStore);
        }
        return httpContext;
    }
    private static CookieStore cookieStore;
    public static CookieStore getCookieStore() {
        if(cookieStore == null) {
            cookieStore = new BasicCookieStore();
        }
        return cookieStore;
    }
}
```

I am not sure if this is the 'Android' way of doing it (using a static class) but it works:

```
    //...
    //Connection objects
    DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(ccm, params);
    HttpPost httpPost = null;

    //Cookie stuff
    HttpContext httpContext = State.getHttpContext();
    httpClient.getParams().setParameter(ClientPNames.COOKIE_POLICY, CookiePolicy.RFC_2109);
    //....
```

It seems using another `HttpClient` every time preserves the session, provided that the same `CookieStore` and `HttpContext` are used.
While this answer makes 'things work' (which is what I needed right now), it is not a thorough answer as it does not explain at all why more than 10 classes are needed to connect everything together.

Comment: Regarding those 10/13 classes you need to wire everything together, that's just how Apache HttpClient rolls: its learning curve is a bit steep, especially if you don't know the nuts and bolts of the HTTP/HTTPS specification. You may call it over-engineered (e.g. `NameValuePair`, really?) or awe at how it provides you with a class for every single concept in HTTP. Either way, chances are that you won't be able to reduce that number, which is the price to pay for using a "highly flexible and functional" library, as HttpClient describes itself.

Comment: It's not just over-engineered. It's a hell of a library. Using it is like being hit with a giant cactus each time I type a character.

You know that something is VERY over-engineered when you need to use 8 different classes just to get a page content and status.